# Transform a list, filtering out the items that cause an exception

Tags: kotlin, reduce, higher-order-functions

How to convert this array of String:

`"2018-05-08T23:22:49Z"`
`"n/a"`
`"2018-05-07T16:37:00Z"`

to an array of Date using Higher-Order Functions such as `map`, `flatMap` or `reduce`?

I do know that it's possible to do that using `forEach`, but I'm interested to involve Kotlin Higher-Order Functions:

```
val stringArray
        = mutableListOf("2018-05-08T23:22:49Z", "n/a", "2018-05-07T16:37:00Z")

val dateArray = mutableListOf<Date>()

stringArray.forEach {
    try {
        val date = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.US)
                .parse(it)
        dateArray.add(date)
    } catch (e: ParseException) {
        //* Just prevents app from crash */
    }
}
```

Comment: you just need to `filter` out "n/a" values and then use `map`, what's the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to keep the bad dates as nulls, or remove them?

Comment: @jrtapsell I'm trying to remove bad dates. Considering given example initial string array of 3 elements should be converted into date array of 2 elements. "n/a" should be ignored and I'm interested in using Kotlin Higher-Order Functions to accomplish that task.

Comment: @pwolaq Thanks, that's the option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a transformation that can output zero or one element per input element. This is `flatMap`. The result of a flatmapping function must be an `Iterable`, so:

```
val dateArray = stringArray.flatMap {
    try {
        listOf(SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.US).parse(it))
    } catch (e: ParseException) {
        emptyList<Date>()
    }
}
```

---

<sup>Adding the following based on `@pwolaq`'s input:</sup>

It's highly recommended to extract the `SimpleDateFormat` instance because it has heavyweight initialization. Further, a solution with `mapNotNull` is cleaner than `flatMap`, I wasn't aware of it. This becomes especially convenient if you add a function that I feel is missing from the Kotlin standard library:

```
inline fun <T> runOrNull(block: () -> T) = try {
    block()
} catch (t: Throwable) {
    null
}
```

With this in your toolbox you can say:

```
val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.US)
val dateArray: List<Date> = stringArray.mapNotNull { 
    runOrNull { formatter.parse(it) } 
}
```

Comment: Cool, that's something I was looking for!

Comment: `mapNotNull` would be a better option

Comment: @pwolaq I used that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50250327/8041461), but for small lists the overhead of the temporary lists shouldn't be too bad, although it should be avoided if possible

Comment: I agree it's better, and it's better to extract the `SimpleDateFormat` instance. It would be better still if there was `tryOrNull` in the standard library.

Answer (score 6):

## Using mapNotNull

```
val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.US)
val dates = listOf("2018-05-08T23:22:49Z", "n/a", "2018-05-07T16:37:00Z")
    .mapNotNull {
        try {
            format.parse(it)
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            null
        }
    }
println(dates)
```

This avoids creating a list for each item in the list, it maps the bad dates to null, and mapNotNull removes the nulls from the list.

## Using an extension function

You could also extract the tryOrRemove to an extension function, making the code look like this:

```
val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.US)

fun <T, U: Any> Iterable<T>.tryOrRemove(block:(T)->U): List<U> {
    return mapNotNull {
        try {
            block(it)
        } catch (ex: Throwable) {
            null
        }
    }
}

val dates = listOf("2018-05-08T23:22:49Z", "n/a", "2018-05-07T16:37:00Z")
    .tryOrRemove(format::parse)

println(dates)
```

## Using filter

I have written it based on the only bad dates being n/a, which simplifies it.

```
val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.US)

val dates = listOf("2018-05-08T23:22:49Z", "n/a", "2018-05-07T16:37:00Z")
    .filter { it != "n/a" }
    .map(format::parse)

println(dates)
```

Comment: `tryOrRemove` is not a good name because it doesn't indicate it's transforming all the items, not just removing those that fail a try-catch test.